# Separate rows from a mysql database into differant variables

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, variables

I'm trying to separate a result into different arrays for each row, then output them into a table. Here is my code.. Its long I know and also outdated, but i just need it to work. Any help would be amazing. Currently it does echo the correct amount of rows, only they are all empty.

```
        <?php
        include ('user.inc');
        mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
        @mysql_select_db($database) or die ("unable to select database");

            $query = 'SELECT * FROM customer LIMIT 50';
            $result=mysql_query($query);
            $num=mysql_numrows($result);

        mysql_close();

            $i=0;

            while ($i = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $customerID[$i]=$i['customerID'];
                $surname[$i]=$i['surname'];
                $forname[$i]=$i['forname'];
                $title[$i]=$i['title'];
                $email[$i]=$i['e-mail'];
                $adress[$i]=$i['address1'];
                $street[$i]=$i['street'];
                $city[$i]=$i['city'];
                $county[$i]=$i['cuunty'];
                $postcode[$i]=$i['postcode'];
                $phoneNumber[$i]=$i['phoneNumber'];
                $mobileNumber[$i]=$i['mobileNumber'];
            $i++;
            }
            $r=0;
            echo'<table>';
            while ($r < $num){
                echo'<tr>';
                echo'<td><form action="userinfo.php"><input type="hidden" name="customerID" value="';
                echo$customerID[$r];
                echo'"><imput type="submit" value="';
                echo$customerID[$r];
                echo'"></form></td>';
                echo'   <td>';
                echo$title[r];
                echo'</td>';
                echo'   <td>';
                echo$surname[r];
                echo'</td>';
                echo'   <td>';
                echo$forname[r];
                echo'</td>';
                echo'   <td>';
                echo$email[r];
                echo'</td>';
                echo'</tr>';
            $r++;
            }
            echo'</table>';
        ?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the same variable for your counter as well as your associative array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
$i=0;

        while ($i = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $customerID[$i]=$i['customerID'];
            $surname[$i]=$i['surname'];
            $forname[$i]=$i['forname'];
            $title[$i]=$i['title'];
            $email[$i]=$i['e-mail'];
            $adress[$i]=$i['address1'];
            $street[$i]=$i['street'];
            $city[$i]=$i['city'];
            $county[$i]=$i['cuunty'];
            $postcode[$i]=$i['postcode'];
            $phoneNumber[$i]=$i['phoneNumber'];
            $mobileNumber[$i]=$i['mobileNumber'];
        $i++;
        }
```

to

```
//$i=0;

        while ($i = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $customerID[]=$i['customerID'];
            $surname[]=$i['surname'];
            $forname[]=$i['forname'];
            $title[]=$i['title'];
            $email[]=$i['e-mail'];
            $adress[]=$i['address1'];
            $street[]=$i['street'];
            $city[]=$i['city'];
            $county[]=$i['cuunty'];
            $postcode[]=$i['postcode'];
            $phoneNumber[]=$i['phoneNumber'];
            $mobileNumber[]=$i['mobileNumber'];
        //$i++;
        }
```

Comment: didnt work sorry, i got a server error instead. Thanks anyway.

Comment: your code contains lots of error. first correct them, after that it will work.

Comment: Thanks very much, great help. id left a second '}' in the code which must have f'ed something up. Thanks again :D

Answer (score 0):

Why are you reading all the data in to an array and then just writing it out?  This is unnecessary and wastes memory.  Put your echo statements into the first loop with references to the relevant array nodes.